# How well can a Mandalorian see?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian, mandalorian

Given the small amount of see-through<sup>1</sup> material in a Mandalorian helmet, how well does a Mandalorian actually see out of one?  By initial looks these helmets have a severely restricted field of view.  Is the field of view purely optical, or is there any sort of vision enhancing technology (a la Iron Man) on the inside of one?

---

[1] And from what I have seen I'm not even sure the optical elements are transparent for the wavelengths normally used by humans.  They seem more appropriate for an IR filter.

Comment: *"Terrible!"* Wait. That's a Sith with no nose.

Comment: Not well at all based on my friend's Boba Fett Halloween costume of 2010, in which he walked into several trees and fell off a curb.

Comment: @Kitkat - In fairness, Boba died because he got whacked with a stick and fell into a hole. so falling off of a curb isn't much worse.

Comment: @Valorum So he got whacked off with a stick?  Wait, that's a Deadpool joke!

Comment: In Legends, Mandalorian helmets would allow 360° vision with the sensor on the top, I assume you're looking for a TV show answer though.

Comment: @Valorum You can cut a Sith in half with lines like that

Comment: Don't we have evidence that there's at least a heads-up display for infrared, etc.?   Why cant all their vision be through that display?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the canon [*Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know) factbook, Mandalorians have excellent vision as a result of their helmets having a "tactical display", presumably one similar to that used by [Imperial Stormtroopers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOwl7lGxEew).

[image]

In several episodes of the Mandalorian TV show , we see through Mando's eyes. His helmet apparently includes optics with some kind of advanced infra-red that can see through solid rock.

[image]
<sub><sup>**Episode 3: The Sin**</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>**Episode 8: Redemption**</sup></sub>